# Angular HttpClient map observable array of objects

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

What is the simplest way to map each object of the result (Rxjs Observable) to an another object when querying an array of objects using angular HttpClient?

I'm currently doing it like below but is there a way to avoid "double mapping"?

In the example the end result needs to be `Observable<Entry[]>` with the constructor called for each `Entry`-object:

```
public getList(): Observable<Entry[]> {
  const url = "/entries/";
  return this.httpClient.get<Entry[]>(url)
    .map((entries: any[]) => entries.map((e) => new Entry(e)));
}
```

Comment: if you use `.map((res:Response) => res.json())` you will get the return value as Observable of `Entry[]` if provided the json structure matches the class properties of `Entry` and you have to return them as an array from the server side.

Comment: You're not exactly *"double mapping"*; one is an Observable.map and the other is an Array.map. Is there actually a *problem* with what you have?

Comment: @Niladri I think `res.json` is automatically called when using angular 4.3.0+. So yes, I could write `return this.httpClient.get<Entry[]>(url);` TS compiler would accept it but actually it would return `Observable<Object[]>` and `Entry` constructor won't be called

Comment: @jonrsharpe It works but I'm new to observables and wonder if there's some simpler way

Comment: When using this code I am getting this error 'any' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Answer (score 1):

That's the best way, no shortcut to mapping both the observable and the array, if Entry has any other members than what you get from the api, or if some members need to be type converted (eg. Entry does something to the data in its constructor). If not though, no mapping is needed.